# Handling Repository and Kafka Transactions

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a use  case where I need to consume from a kafka topic, do some work ,produce to another kafka topic with only once semantics and save to a mongo database .After going through  docs what I figure is that the kafka transaction and mongo transaction can be synchronized but they are still  two different transactions .In the below scenario if the mongo commit fails is there a way to roll back the kafka record that was committed to the topic and replayed from consumer.

```
producer.send()
producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction()
mongoDao.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the listener throws an exception, the kafka transaction will be rolled back and redelivered.

If the mongo commit succeeds and the kafka commit fails, you will need to deal with a duplicate delivery.

If you wire the `KafkaTransactionManager` (or a `KafkaChainedTransactionManager` containing one) into the listener container, you don't need to send the offsets to the transaction, the container will do it for you before committing.

Comment: Thanks Gary.I guess if mongo commit fails and kafka succeeds  then I will loose a record in mongo  which is what I am more concerned .
Does this apply even if I chain  the kafka tm and mongo tm  and have  a send method with @transactional.
On the other hand I have another case where I am consuming and producing to another Kafka topic with(kafkatemplate.send,kafkatemplate.sendoffsetsToTransaction,h@transactional )  since I am using retries)what happens if kafkatemplate.send is succesful and kafkatemplate.sendoffsetsToTransaction fails ? Will the transaction be rolled back in this case?

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's hard to read; edit the question instead. NO. If the mongo commit fails (and throws an exception), the kafka transaction will roll back and the message redelivered. Retry is irrelevant - the retries are performed within the kafka transaction. So, if you use `@Transactional` with the mongo TM, you'll get a new mongo TX for each delivery attempt. When the retries are exhausted the kafka transaction will roll back. Again; it's best to let the container send the offsets to the transaction.

Comment: Will make a note of it Gary.The idea to use template to sendsoffsets is to make retries transactional,read from the topic again and produce.Also when using  executeintransaction with a kafka template
and @ transactional method when does the record actually get commited to kafka.In other words when will a consumer using read_commited be able to see this transaction.

Comment: Again; let the container manage the transaction. As explained in the documentation/javadocs, if you use `template.executeIntransaction()`, it will start a new transaction instead of participating in the transaction that the container starts.